# PR for Bitbucket repo -> Triggers AzureDevops CI Pipeline build?

Tags: git, azure, continuous-integration, bitbucket, azure-pipelines

I have *imported* Git repos to AzureDevOps Repos before (dev.azure.com) and then was able to go to `Repos` -> `Branches` -> `master` and set a `Branch Policy` such that any new Pull Request (PR) to *that* master branch in-question *triggers* a CI (build pipeline) build on AzureDevOps Pipelines.

I am trying to do this again, *however*, I do *not* have *this* repository locally on AzureDevOps Repos (dev.azure.com). This time, it's owned by another team at my work, and it is on Bitbucket. I selected `Other Git` in the `Get sources` option when creating the new CI pipeline on AzureDevops (Bitbucket Cloud would *not* let me login and thus I could not use that option. I am not sure if our Bitbucket repo is even the same product as Bitbucket cloud):
[image]

Thus, I can't normally select the Branch of the repo to add a `PR Trigger` to it as I normally would, since this repo doesn't exist/live here on AzureRepos. Does anyone know how I can achieve what I am trying to do? Again, I want new Pull Requests that get merged into `master` branch of the *Bitbucket* repo to Trigger a CI build for **THIS** ci pipeline I am creating on AzureDevops Pipelines.

Comment: how are you accessing it? bitbucket URL or some local\custom URL? if via bitcucket url then this is on bitbucket cloud.

Comment: "Bitbucket Cloud would not let me login and thus I could not use that option." what do you mean? what was the problem?

Answer (score 1):

### Bitbucket Cloud

Use Oauth to access your resources in bitbucket (or user and password if you prefer) or you can [create service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) on your own in the project settings:

[image]

After that go to triggers tab and check "Enable pull request validation":

[image]

### Other Git

Is is not possible to create PR trigger here.

> Pull request validation (PR) triggers also vary based on the type of
> repository.
>
> - PR triggers in Azure Repos Git
> - PR triggers in GitHub
> - PR triggers in Bitbucket Cloud

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops#classic-build-pipelines-and-yaml-pipelines

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout CI triggers and PR triggers for Azure Pipelines for Azure Repos, GitHub and Bitbucket Cloud from here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops